# How to deal with "DNN module was not built with CUDA backend; switching to CPU" warning in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo, darknet

I am trying to run YOLOv3 on Visual Studio 2019 using CUDA 10.2 with cuDNN v7.6.5 on Windows 10 using NVidia GeForce 930M. Here is part of the code I used.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Load names of classes
    string classesFile = "coco.names";
    ifstream ifs(classesFile.c_str());
    string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line)) classes.push_back(line);

    // Give the configuration and weight files for the model
    String modelConfiguration = "yolovs.cfg";
    String modelWeights = "yolov3.weights";

    // Load the network
    Net net = readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights);
    net.setPreferableBackend(DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
    net.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CUDA);

    // Open the video file
    inputFile = "vid.mp4";
    cap.open(inputFile);

    // Get frame from the video
    cap >> frame;

    // Create a 4D blob from a frame
    blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1 / 255.0, Size(inpWidth, inpHeight), Scalar(0, 0, 0), true, false);

    // Sets the input to the network
    net.setInput(blob);

    // Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
    vector<Mat> outs;
    net.forward(outs, getOutputsNames(net));
}
```

Although I add **$(CUDNN)\include;$(cudnn)\include;** to **Additional Include Directories** in both **C/C++** and **Linker**, added **CUDNN_HALF;CUDNN;** to **C/C++>Preprocessor Definitions**, and added **cudnn.lib;** to **Linker>Input**, I still get this warning:

> DNN module was not built with CUDA backend; switching to CPU

and it runs on CPU instead of GPU, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: This question is about building an OpenCV module, not CUDA and not CUDNN. That is why I removed the tags. There is no CUDA or CUDNN related programming question here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using **CMake**, but I had first to add this [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) then rebuilding it using **Visual Studio**. Make sure that these **WITH_CUDA**, **WITH_CUBLAS**, **WITH_CUDNN**, **OPENCV_DNN_CUDA**, **BUILD_opencv_world** are checked in **CMake**.

Comment: DNN module was not built with Cuda backend switching to CPU.I was trying it on pyimage  yolo object detection.

Comment: @rakshitks Try to check these parameters in CMake " WITH_CUDA, WITH_CUBLAS, WITH_CUDNN, OPENCV_DNN_CUDA, BUILD_opencv_world"

Comment: ya everything is there but still when i run the file same problem comes.

Comment: @rakshitks What is the specifications of your machine? and what is the operating system? and which compiler do you use?

Comment: i7 processor 8Gb ram 2Gb graphics card

Comment: @rakshitks even I tried with pyimage search it didnt worked for me either. It throws error of missing libcodec.so... 
Please update if you have any resolution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue happen to me about a week ago, but I was using Python and Tensorflow. Although the languages were different compared to C++, I did get the same error. To fix this, I uninstalled CUDA 10.2 and downgraded to CUDA 10.1. From what I have found, there might be a dependency issue with CUDA, or in your case, OpenCV hasn't created support yet for the latest version of CUDA.

**EDIT**

After some further research it seems to be an issue with Opencv rather than CUDA. Referencing this [github thread](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15858), if you installed Opencv with cmake, remove the arch bin version below 7 on the config file, then rebuild/reinstall Opencv. **However**, if that doesn't work, another option would be to remove CUDA arch bin version < 5.3 and rebuild.

Comment: You completely uninstalled CUDA 10.2, using their GUI, and restarted? Before you installed CUDA 10.1?

Comment: Yes, no difference

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef I made some edits, hope they help.

Comment: I am using Windows and installed OpenCV without cmake, so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: please, how i can remove the arch bin version below 7 on the config file ?