# Deep learning on a computer without CUDA

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

Deep Learning (DNN) in opencv If you specify CUDA for backend and target, It works even if CUDA is not installed on the PC, but in this case, what settings are it running?
Also, I couldn't find a way to get the current settings, so if anyone knows please let me know.

```cpp
net->setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA); 
net->setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);
```

With this setting, deep learning can be performed even on a computer without CUDA. why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without CUDA it falls back to CPU back-end which is functionally same but not as fast as GPU.

Refer
[How to deal with "DNN module was not built with CUDA backend; switching to CPU" warning in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095996/how-to-deal-with-dnn-module-was-not-built-with-cuda-backend-switching-to-cpu)

Comment: thank you!  where is that information? I would like to know for future reference.

Comment: added a reference where OP faced the same thing.